# PHP Laravel: Convert foreach loop result to json

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to create a json of the result for this code with no success, I know I could prossibly hardcode but that has been to no avail.

```
if ($actionFunct == "listSMSs") {
foreach ($client->account->messages as $message) {
    echo "From: {$message->from}\nTo: {$message->to}\nBody: " . $message->body;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

store them in array (multidimensional will also do, if required). then collect & convert to json like this:

```
//make an array.

$collection = collect($array);
$json = $collection->toJson();
```

here you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work but you will have to do the foreach loop in the view

**Controller**

```
 $data = $client->account->messages;
 return response()->json($data);
```

**View**

```
  @foreach($data as $msg)
 {{ $msg->from}} To : {{ $msg->to }}
 @endforeach
```

you can loop the json response using javascript too

if this dosent help can you explain more what do you want to do with the result?